# Parsing parameters in URLs using Zend_Controller_Router_Route

Tags: zend-framework

On my site I need to have URLs of pages in this manner: `/category/page4`, so parameter passed into a controller is a number after the word "page". I managed to get URLs in the following manner: `/category/page/4` (with an extra slash) using this code:

```
$router->addRoute('categoryPages', new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
    '/category/page/:page',
     array(
        'controller' => 'caegory',
        'action' => 'index'
    ),
    array(
        'page' => '\d+'
    )
));
```

I would expect to have URLs like `/category/page4` with the following modification of this code:

```
// Simply removed one slash
'/category/page:page'
```

However, this code doesn't create routing I need. What is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with `Zend_Controller_Router_Route`, named variables must sit on their own adjacent to either the url delimiter (slash), or the start/end of the route.

Instead you could do this as a regular expression route:

```
$router->addRoute('categoryPages', new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex(
    'category/page(\d+)',
     array(
        'controller' => 'caegory',
        'action' => 'index'
    ),
    array(
        1 => 'page'
    ),
    'category/page%s'
));
```